# Grails clear hasMany entries and add new ones error?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am currently working on a grails applications and I have a list of addresses that are attached to an account. Basically what I want to do is when the Account is edited is displays a current list of all the attached Addresses and then I can delete/add as many as I want from the view. When this data is captured it is picked up by the controller and what I want to do is to be able to clear all of the current Addresses from this account and then create the list again with what exists on the view, my code is below:

**Account Domain:**

```
class Account {

    String name
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [addresses:Addresses]

    static mapping = {
        addresses cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }

    def getAddressesList() {
        return LazyList.decorate(
              addresses,
              FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Addresses.class))
    }

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false, unique: true)
    }

}
```

**Address Domain:**

```
class Addresses {

    int indexVal
    String firstLine
    String postcode
    String area

    static belongsTo = [account:Account]

    static mapping = {
    }

    static transients = [ 'deleted' ]

    static constraints = {
        indexVal(blank:false, min:0)
    }


}
```

**Account Controller:**

```
def update() {

    def accountInstance = Account.get(params.id)
    if (!accountInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'account.label', default: 'Account'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (params.version) {
        def version = params.version.toLong()
        if (accountInstance.version > version) {
            accountInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'subscriptions.label', default: 'Subscriptions')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this Account while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [accountInstance: accountInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    accountInstance.properties = params

    accountInstance.addresses.clear()
    accountInstance.save(flush: true)

    ....

}
```

**Error:**

> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.tool.Account.addresses. Stacktrace follows:
>       Message: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.tool.Account.addresses

This error seems to be occurring in the controller on line:

```
accountInstance.save(flush: true)
```

I have tried several different way to get this to work and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Shouldn't `clear()` be before `params` set to `properties`? Swap those 2 lines.

Comment: I have tried that but still get the same error :S

Comment: if I remove the line (addresses cascade:"all-delete-orphan") from the Accounts domain and then have the controller clear the address and add the new ones I dont get an error but it just adds them onto the list already there creating some duplicates, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it seems like you have done some work that Grails can do for you.

```
class Account {

    String name
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    List addresses

    static hasMany = [addresses:Address]

    static mapping = {
        addresses cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false, unique: true)
    }

}

class Address {
    String firstLine
    String postcode
    String area

    static belongsTo = [account:Account]
}
```

This will produce the effect you want of having addresses being a list.

I've found either

```
instance.addresses = null
```

or

```
instance.addresses.clear()
```

to work for me

Answer (score -1):

When you define `addresses cascade:"all-delete-orphan"` in `Account` class you don't need `static belongsTo = [account:Account]` in `Addresses`. So just try to remove that statement and test your code. See related [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html).

Comment: The belongsTo and cascade strategy have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: **This is used when** you want to delete addresses when **account is deleted**. **But** the question asks for **clear the list of addresses without delete the account**